# adding custom details to android calendar events

Tags: android, android-calendar

I am using the native calendar using content providers for my android app. I need to set and use some custom values for each event in my calendar and I will be using those values to process certain operations in my app.

When I explored the options I found are
1. Using [extended Properties](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.ExtendedProperties.html)
2. Using [custom content providers](https://www.grokkingandroid.com/android-tutorial-writing-your-own-content-provider/)

I tried with option 1 using a solution provided by someone in Stackoverflow...

```
Uri extendedProperties=Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/extendedproperties");
ContentValues extendedValues=new ContentValues();
extendedValues.put("event_id", id);
extendedValues.put("name",key);
extendedValues.put("value",value);
getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().insert(extendedProperties, extendedValues);
```

but this gives error when executing getContentResolver with a nullpointer exception...
And I am using this in a normal class and it is not extending an activity as my main activity will call the function in this class to get the calendar details...

Also help me what is the good solution for this if there are any other approaches...

Thanks for time and effort

Comment: Please add some more information. First of all a full StackTrace would help. Also some more information about the snippet above. Is it part of a Service, an Activity? What's the context of those lines. And please mention which line numbers the snippets corresponds to. That's helpful for understanding the logcat output.

Comment: Thanks @WolframRittmeyer let me try to recreate it...

Comment: It was due to the non availability of context inside the class which I was using with the above statements.. But even after using context I got "only syncadapters can access extended properties" error with illegalargumenexception... since my need is not suitable for syncadaptor I am using SQLite now.. Thanks for your time..

Comment: Im also want solution for this qyestion